# Connecting Rails app deployed on Heroku to my own MongoDB server

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, database, mlab

I've deployed a Rails app on Heroku using MongoDB add-on mLab. As I have a huge amount of data and a server, I want to connect my app to my own hosted MongoDB server. Is it possible with Heroku? And if yes, how can I do this?

Comment: You're deploying a heroku app, using a DB from a heroku add-on? In this case go read that add-on's documentation. Configuration must be covered there (if not handled automatically for you).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It's working well now with the add-on but I want to change to my own MongoDB server! That's the problem!

Comment: Ah, I see. In this case, inspect your app's mongoid.yml and settings (environment variables on heroku). I'm betting that you'll find a couple of variables which you'll need to change to point to your server instead of mLab.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Do you know if it's feasible or not? If Heroku lets us or not?!

Comment: Of course, it's possible. Heroku doesn't care.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I hope so! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just put your M-Lab credentials in your Heroku Environment Variables. You can get to them via the command line or on the settings tab in the Heroku console. They have an environment variable named `MONGODB_URI` (created when you add M-Lab through the console). Simply put your M-Lab credentials in that ENV VAR (or create it) and have your config use that environment variable to determine your connection string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's not my problem. I'm using mLab, I wanted to know if it's possible to change it to my own MongoDB server or not? And if yes, how?

Comment: You just need to have a MongoDB server that is set up and connected to the internet. As long as the Mongo connection string has the valid credentials and uri, Heroku doesn't care where it's hosted. But your db must be served from somewhere. So you need to use the mongo connect string: `mongdb://username:password@your.server.domain.com:port/dbname`